# One WCF service on two addresses

Tags: c#, wcf

My situation:

I have one WCF service on address `http://0.0.0.0:10004/Service.svc`. Using `Interface_1`, `Service_1_Class`, `ServiceHost_1_Class`.

Now I need second version of this service with authorisation. Choosing address `https://0.0.0.0:10004/Service2.svc`, using `Interface_1`, `Service_1_Class`, `ServiceHost_2_Class`.

Got the error 
HTTP could not register URL `https://+:10004/Service2.svc/`. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS.

If copy-paste and use `Interface_2`, `Service_2_Class`, `ServiceHost_2_Class` (same classes with different name) everything works.

Not the big problem, but want to know: how to bind same service class on two addresses? So which step may I miss? I.e. binding one to one works, binding one to two - not, where is difference? If there should not be differences (i.e. problem in code), I'll close this question.

PS: sorry, cant post code: too big, too complicated, not clear. Question not about code, but conception

Comment: Make sure your tests are pure. Are you sure you used the same port when you tried with Interface_2? Are you sure there wasn't another instance of your application running that blocked the port at the time?
Why not add the second service to the same host, why another host instance?

Comment: yes. Problem not in url (many tries confirm). View connections with tcpview (sysinternals).

Comment: "Why not add the second service to the same host, why another host instance?" - could you explain, pls? I  use base classes, developed in our company, this scheme is common for our products.

Comment: I think you need to seup multiple endpoints https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you need to setup multiple service endpoints each with a different binding. One binding with no security enabled and the other binding with security enabled.

Here is a working example of how to host the same service at two different endpoints. One endpoint has no security at all and the other endpoint provides HTTP-based client authentication.

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:10004/");
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldService), baseUri);
try
{
    var unsecureServiceEndpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), new WebHttpBinding(), "Service.svc");
    unsecureServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    unsecureServiceEndpoint.Name = "UnsecureEndpoint";

    var secureBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
    secureBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    var secureServiceEndpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHelloWorldService), secureBinding, "Service2.svc");
    secureServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    secureServiceEndpoint.Name = "SecureEndpoint";

    serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
    serviceHost.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Hosting - {0} @ {1}", unsecureServiceEndpoint.Name, unsecureServiceEndpoint.Address);
    Console.WriteLine("Hosting - {0} @ {1}", secureServiceEndpoint.Name, secureServiceEndpoint.Address);

    Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the services.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    serviceHost.Close();
}
catch (CommunicationException ce)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
    serviceHost.Abort();
}
```